# keyboard.next not receiving input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

For some reason my keyboard will not input anything when prompted to do so. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ForgetfulMachine {
    public static void main( String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println( "What city is the capital of France?" );
        keyboard.next();

        System.out.println( "What is 6 multiplied by 7?");
        keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println( "Enter a number between 0.0 and 1.0");
        keyboard.nextDouble();

        System.out.println( "Is there anything else you would like to say?");
        keyboard.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you try to write the console?

Comment: You are not using the value returned by `keyboard.next()`

Comment: Are you trying to get the values that you are typing? Because your code accepts anything, and just moves on

Comment: Hello @HNO3 (are you really as acidic as the nitric acid?), if my answer helped you, mark it as [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). It will increase your rep too ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the value returned by [`next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) into some variable, like so:

```
String input = keyboard.next();
// for int or float input, use appropriate variable type to store the input

// possibly print it to the console
System.out.println("You entered: " + input);
```